# Increasing precision in \pgfmathsetmacro

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I would like to use

```
\pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac]{\var}
```

where `\var` is a variable set by `\pgfmathsetmacro` and I'm having similar difficulties as in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45151/format-numbers-as-a-fraction-of-pi-with-tikz-pgfmathprintnumber) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54702/pgfmathsetmacro-dimension-too-large-biggest-value-allowed) question. I'm aware that the *frac* format is numerically unstable.

My problem is that the precision of `\pgfmathsetmacro` seems to be five digits, but for the following minimal example I'd need seven digits. Is there a trick to do it?

---

### **EDIT:**

The following solutions are possible (I haven't decided which one is the best.. please vote!)

- Package *xintexpr* and `round(x,10)` to have precision 10 result (by @jfbu)

  - changes just the division
- `frac shift=2` (by @Qrrbrbirlbel)

  - simple addition
  - no additional packages
- *fixed point arithmetic* of tikz to calculate a more precise result (also by @Qrrbrbirlbel)

  - newcommand, but otherwise also just changes the division

---

*Original post continued*
See this example:

- blue my first attempt
- black with fpu
- red: what I want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\usepackage{fp} % uncommenting results in the following warning, but no change in output
%! Package pgf /pgf/number format/frac warning=true: /pgf/number format/frac of
%`3.3333e-1' = 100009 / 300030 might be large due to instabilities. Try \usepack
%age{fp} to improve accuracy.

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\nu{4}
\def\w{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nn}{\nu-1}
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,\nn}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xi}{\i*\w/(\nu-1)}
  % first test
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xival}{\i/(\nu-1)}
  \draw[blue] (\xi, -1.1 cm) -- (\xi,2pt)  node[above,align=center] 
     {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=10]{\xival} \\ 
     \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac]{\xival}};

  % second test (fpu)
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
  \pgfmathparse{\i/(\nu-1)}
  \edef\tmp{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
  \draw (\xi,2pt) -- (\xi, -1.1 cm) node[below,align=center] 
      {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=10]{\tmp} \\ 
      \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac]{\tmp}};
  } % end foreach

% this works (two digits '3' added)
\node[red] at (1,-.5) {\pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac]{0.3333333}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Extract from pgfmanual: "The FPU’s relative
precision is at least 1·10^−4 although operations like addition have a relative precision of 1·10^−6". So, no trick to increase relative precision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `0.33333` is simply too imprecise for the high precision that `/frac` and `fp` offers as 100009/300030 (which is 0.3¯33330000) is nearer to 0.33333 than to 1/3.

You can work around this by giving the option `/pgf/number format/frac shift=2` (initially `4`) or by using `fp` also for the division.

### Code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fp,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu,fixedpointarithmetic}
\newcommand*{\pgfMathsetmacro}[2]{\pgfmathparse{#2}\let#1\pgfmathresult}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.5cm]
\def\nu{4} \def\w{5}
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,\the\numexpr\nu-1}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro\xival{\i/(\nu-1)}
  \draw (\i,0pt) node[above,align=center] 
    {{\tiny\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=10]{\xival}} \\ 
           \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/.cd, frac, frac shift=2]{\xival}};

  \tikzset{fixed point arithmetic}
  \pgfMathsetmacro\xival{\i/(\nu-1)}
  \draw (\i,-1) node[above,align=center] 
    {{\tiny\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=10]{\xival}} \\ 
           \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac]{\xival}};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Exact or arbitrarily precise computations with fractions are possible with package `xintfrac`, and made easier with `\xintexpr ... \relax` provided by package `xintexpr` (which loads `xintfrac`). See [xint bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint).

So here we use the `round(x,10)` function inside `xinttheexpr...\relax` to define a macro `\tmp` by an `\edef` to be the fraction rounded to 10 digits after the decimal mark.

Note though that apart from `sqrt` only  addition, multiplication, division, subtraction, and powers with integral exponents are possible.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\usepackage{xintexpr} % http://ctan.org/pkg/xint

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\nu{4}
\def\w{5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\nn}{\nu-1}
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,\nn}{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xi}{\i*\w/(\nu-1)}
  % first test
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\xival}{\i/(\nu-1)}
  \draw[blue] (\xi, -1.1 cm) -- (\xi,2pt)  node[above,align=center] 
     {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=10]{\xival} \\ 
     \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac]{\xival}};

  % second test (fpu)
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}
  \pgfmathparse{\i/(\nu-1)}
  \edef\tmp{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
  \draw (\xi,2pt) -- (\xi, -1.1 cm) node[below,align=center] 
      {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=10]{\tmp} \\ 
      \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac]{\tmp}};

  % third test (xintexpr)
  \edef\tmp{\xinttheexpr round(\i/(\nu-1),10)\relax}
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
  \draw[blue] (\xi,-2.1cm)
           -- (\xi, -3.2cm) node[below,align=center] 
      {\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed, precision=10]{\tmp} \\ 
      \pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac]{\tmp}};

} % end foreach

% this works (two digits '3' added)
\node[red] at (1,-.5) {\pgfmathprintnumber[/pgf/number format/frac]{0.3333333}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: use of xint]